# How to know the significance of coefficients and model in Weka?

Tags: r, model, weka, significance

I have been using R to model data using linear regression. And using the "summary(model)" command, it will provide details of coefficients significance and model significance (F-statistic). Can Weka provide such measures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Weka for linear regression, it outputs the full model with coefficient for each attribute used (except if "output model" is unchecked in options). As an exemple, using the cpu.arff dataset:

```
Linear Regression Model

class =

  0.2122 * MYCT +
  0.019  * MMIN +
  0.0026 * MMAX +
  1.2604 * CACH +
  8.0792 * CHMIN +
 -1.5828 * CHMAX +
-53.7929
```

Comment: Aha! What about the model significance (F-statistic)?

Comment: Please check "Output per-class stats" in "Options". It will work for classifiers (ie. not for linear regression or similar because its formula is based on Precision and Recall).